# K means self-developped vs K means on skikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means

So I am trying to learn the K-means clustering algorithm, and my way of learning is trying to rebuild Kmeans on my own.

Here is the data: https://www.kaggle.com/code/agajorte/people-body-mass-index-clustering

And this is the imaginary problem: "Given the data of height and weight of random 500 people (250 male, 250 female), use machine learning to group them of different sizes for t-shirt."

For simplicity (because I am still learning), I only stick with the male data and pre-assuming that there are only three sizes: large, medium, and small.

Here is my code following the K-means procedure:

```
data = df[['Height','Weight']].loc['Male']
data = data.reset_index(drop = True)
data['Label'] = ''

#Picking random centroids for each clusters, you could also use the Random library (I already tested as long as large is largest and small is smallest)

    K = {'large': [180,120],
         'medium': [170, 80],
         'small': [150,60],
         } 

#Should be a while loop, but I don't know the stop condition, so I just use for loop and test with big number of loops
for loop_num in range(50):


    for i in range(len(data)):
#a is the point closest to one of the 3 declared centroid
        a = min(
            abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['large'][0]**2 + K['large'][1]**2)),
            abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['medium'][0]**2 + K['medium'][1]**2)),
            abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['small'][0]**2 + K['small'][1]**2))
        )

#with a, we can lable the data

        if a == abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['large'][0]**2 + K['large'][1]**2)):
            data.loc[i,'Label'] = 3
        elif a == abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['medium'][0]**2 + K['medium'][1]**2)):
            data.loc[i,'Label'] = 2
        elif a == abs((data['Height'].loc[i]**2 + data['Weight'].loc[i]**2)-(K['small'][0]**2 + K['small'][1]**2)):
            data.loc[i,'Label'] = 1

#we replace Ks with better Ks (using the lable, for example: mean of all '3' data will be the new centroid for 'large')

    K = {'large': [float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 3, ['Height']])),float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 3, ['Weight']]))],
                    'medium': [float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 2, ['Height']])),float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 2, ['Weight']]))],
                    'small': [float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 1, ['Height']])),float(DataFrame.mean(data.loc[data['Label'] == 1, ['Weight']]))],
                    }
print(K)
```

Running this multiple times with different values here and there, my result is really consistent and logical:

```
{'large': [179.60638297872342, 132.56382978723406], 'medium': [169.23076923076923, 96.38461538461539], 'small': [150.6595744680851, 75.7872340425532]}
```

However, I can't achieve the same result using KMeans from skikit learn

```
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='random',tol = 30)
X = data[['Height','Weight']]
clusterer.fit(X)
print(clusterer.cluster_centers_)
```

Every time I hit run, I get different results.

I tried changing the parameters in KMeans(). I have different results every time, but nothing makes sense logically.

For example this is the result of one of the runs:

```
[[168.85227273 141.78409091]
 [170.82432432 105.01351351]
 [169.44578313  69.86746988]]
```

Here is the graph of my centroids vs the data:
[image]

And here is the graph of sklearn (keep in mind that this is just one out of the runs)

[image]

Comment: I think `[168.85227273 141.78409091]` is the centroid of large, `[170.82432432 105.01351351]` the centroid of medium and `[169.44578313  69.86746988]` the centroid of small. it makes sense to me. What is your doubt precisely? (The result is different everytime because the starting point is random everytime)

Comment: Given that your data is 2d you can plot it to assure yourself that the centroids make sense

Comment: You can give your initial guesses to scikit with the `init` argument and see if it gives the same result as your code

Comment: Hi, the algorithm I built on my own always get:
{'large': [179.60638297872342, 132.56382978723406], 'medium': [169.23076923076923, 96.38461538461539], 'small': [150.6595744680851, 75.7872340425532]}
as the result regardless of my starting (as long as the large is largest, and small is smallest as I mentioned). So I would expect scikit learn to do the same because it is the same algorithm.

Comment: if you do a plot of the points, your centroids and those of sklearn which ones make more sense?

Comment: It would be my own centroids

Comment: Edited: I attached the graphs for reference